# very slow connecting/finding printer & scanner Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, upgrade, printing, 22.04, scanner

After turning on or restarting my PC, my ubuntu 22.04 can connect to the available network printer/scanner.

After some time, the connection to the printer/scanner went off.

So after this period, when I print, it takes some time to search the printer before it can print. The worst is the scanner; the document scanner keeps searching for more than 10min, and sometimes it is not responding.

After restarting the computer, everything returns to normal, and I can print and scan without waiting a long time. Then, the same problem repeats.

I don't have this problem with the previous ubuntu 18.04.
I recently upgraded to 20.04 (using it only for about 2 weeks) and then to 22.04.

Thank you.

system info:
Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, 64-bit, GNOME version 42.4, Windowing system: Wayland.

Comment: Part of this makes perfect sense. After not being used for a while the connection times out. Why it takes 10 mins for the scanner to re connect no idea.

Comment: Yes. It is about the long waiting during the search of the printer/scanner. It is so slow... also very slow when I open the  "Printers" window, before I can see all the printers available in the network. It is not like this before (18.04), or when using windows (dual boot) on the same PC.